# Git color merge/rebase conflicts

Tags: git

I was wondering if someone had a trick to color the ouput of a merge or rebase when there is a conflict.
I want to color specially the line with the filename, for example the second line here :

```
Auto-merging CMakeLists.txt
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in CMakeLists.txt
Failed to merge in the changes.
```

Thanks

EDIT :

Using git alias and a bash function I can write this :

```
color-merge = "!f() { git merge --no-commit --stat $1| egrep --color 'CONFLICT .*|$'; }; f"
```

This will color all the conflict lines but :

- It's impossible to change the options passed to merge
- There is no completion on the branch to be tracked

So I'm looking for something more powerful.

Cheers

Comment: `git config --global color.ui auto` ?!

Comment: I have color = always but that does not do what I want.

Comment: it's crazy that git still doesn't support color on CONFLICT after two years from this question!

Answer (score 6):

Another option might be to create a [git alias](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Tips-and-Tricks#Git-Aliases). This is preferable to me because it keeps keep git-specific customizations together instead of floating elsewhere in an unrelated `.profile` file somewhere.

Adding something like this to your `~/.gitconfig` or the local git project's `.git/config` should also work:

```
[alias]
    color-merge = "!f() { git merge $@ | egrep --color 'CONFLICT .*|$' ; }; f"
```

Invoke it like so: `git color-merge branch --option1`

Note that your shell's [`GREP_COLOR` environment variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Environment-Variables.html) will control the color used.

Comment: Somebody correct me if I'm wrong, but this approach is taking advantage of the [shellshock](http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2014-6271) vulnerability in bash, right? Or maybe it just looks similar. It isn't using an ENV var after all.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question referenced from newer questions, and it's the first one that appears on my Google search results, so I think it's convenient to post the updated answer 5 years later:

Just add the line `unmerged = <color>` into `[color "status"]` group in your git settings file (`~/.gitconfig`), like this:

```
[color "status"]
     unmerged  = yellow
```

I'm using `git --version` **2.11.0**. So yeah, finally git supported it :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
[color]
  branch = auto
  diff = auto
  status = auto

[color "branch"]
  current = yellow reverse
  local = yellow
  remote = green

[color "diff"]
  meta = yellow bold
  frag = magenta bold
  old = red bold
  new = green bold

[color "status"]
  added = yellow
  changed = green
  untracked = cyan

http://jblevins.org/log/git-colors
```

So no colors for a merge conflict I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Indeed that can't be achieved with only git config, but it must be possible by adding bash commands.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bash function that gets you there (except for branch completion):

```
   git-merge-color () { git merge  $@ | egrep --color 'CONFLICT .*|$'; }
```

You can invoke git-merge-color with any 'git merge' arguments that you please.

Comment: How would I apply/invoke this? It looks really promising to me, but I'm a complete noob when it comes to bash.